# Storing data in two tables at a time in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have three tables

1. Products { pid, pname, price }
2. Orders { oid, odate }
3. OrderDetails { odid, oid, pid, qty, total }

I've a form which upon submission passes an array of OrderDetails which I want to store in database. But the tragedy here is I want to store current date in Order table at the same time. Now my Order table is getting populated with odate but nothing is getting inserted in my orderdetails table. And I'm using web api and the array is fetched correctly in controller. I guess this line

```
aOrder.AllOrders.Add(od);
```

in the controller has to be replaced with somethting else.

Order.cs

```
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int oid { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime odate { get; set; }
    public virtual List<OrderDetail> AllOrders { get; set; }
    public Order()
    {
        AllOrders = new List<OrderDetail>();
    }
}
```

OrderDetail.cs

```
public class OrderDetail
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int odid { get; set; }
    public int oid { get; set; }
    public virtual Order order { get; set; }
    public int pid { get; set; }
    public int qty { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Aproduct { get; set; }
    public OrderDetail()
    {
        Aproduct = new Product();
    }
}
```

OrderDetailsController.cs

```
    private static readonly IOrderDetailRepository _orders = new OrderDetailRepository();

    public Order Post(List<OrderDetail> orderDetails)
    {
        Order aOrder = new Order();   
        foreach(OrderDetail orderDetail in orderDetails)
        {
            OrderDetail od = new OrderDetail();
            od.oid = orderDetail.oid;
            od.pid = orderDetail.pid;
            od.qty = orderDetail.qty;
            od.total = orderDetail.total;
            aOrder.AllOrders.Add(od);
        }
        aOrder.odate = DateTime.Now;
        return _orders.Add(aOrder);

    }
```

OrderDetailRepository.cs

```
    public Order Add(Order order)
    {
        _db.Orders.Add(order);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return order;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try specifying a foreign key for OrderDetails:

```
public class OrderDetail
{
[ForeignKey("Order")]
public int oid { get; set; } //I'm guessing this is Order's PK
```

Comment: I already done the mapping in all models, so I don't have to specify separately which one is foreign key as all models are already related right? I guess that's not the problem. I tried doing that anyway and it game me error while fetching data. So I removed it again.